Modal Bootstrap
Estoy intentando abrir y cerrar un Modal desde una función mientras tengo abierto un primer modal. Mi problema es que, cuando se ejecuta la función el Modal no se activa al inicio de esta sino que se activa al final. Lo que intento es en una función llamar otra función que abre el Modal, y al final de la función, llamar otra función que cierre este Modal, pero lo dentro de la función que llama a las otras dos funciones, primero se ejecuta la función que cierra el modal y al final la función que abre el modal.
 function enviarCorreo() {
    procesoon();//activa un segundo modal y esto se ejecuta al final
    Desactivabtn();
    var id = document.getElementById("Facturaid").value;
    var correo = document.getElementById("Mails").value;
    var copia = document.getElementById("Concopia").value;
    var body = document.getElementById("Bbody").value;
    $.get("CRP/EnviarCorreo/?id=" + id + "&para=" + correo + "&copia=" + copia + "&msg=" + body, function (data) {
        if (data == "1") {
            Activabtn();
            alert("Correo enviado correctamente.");
            document.getElementById("btnClose").click();
        }
        else {
            Activabtn();
            document.getElementById("DivError").innerHTML = data;
        }
        procesooff();//desactiva el segundo modal, esto se ejecuta primero
    })
}


Debes mejorar la explicación de tu pregunta, así como está es difícil de entender y por sobre todo agregar un [MCVE] que refleje el problema que describes, porque en tú códigos todas esas funciones se ejecutan en orden
